# Cannot connect to SMTP (Docker) from Gitlab (Docker) on the same server

Tags: docker, email, gitlab, smtp

I didn't succeed to configure a SMTP connection in a dockerized Gitlab instance.

*The particularity :* Gitlab AND Postfix are in Docker instances on the same server, with the same domain.

**Current state:**

- A mail server running with `docker.io/mailserver/docker-mailserver` image

  - All ports are binded on host : 25, 143, 465, 587, 993
- A Gitlab server running with `gitlab/gitlab-ce:14.3.5-ce.0` image

  - Omnibus configuration :

```rb
external_url 'https://gitlab.my-domain.io'
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "my-domain.io"
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 465
gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_ssl'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "gitlab@my-domain.io"
gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "XXXXXXXXX"
gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login"
gitlab_rails['smtp_openssl_verify_mode'] = 'peer'
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = 'gitlab@my-domain.io'
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_reply_to'] = 'gitlab@my-domain.io'
```

I specify that I tried many configuration tweaks : `smtp_tls`, `smtp_ssl`, `smtp_domain`, `smtp_enable_starttls_auto`...

**How I test:**

In the Gitlab container :

```sh
gitlab-rails console
Notify.test_email('my_email@my_host.com', 'Message Subject', 'Message Body').deliver_now
```

Result :

```sh
Delivered mail 61a8fdff8d22f_10a65a14-4ea@gitlab.my-domain.io.mail (30003.5ms)
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):2
Net::OpenTimeout (execution expired)
```

**Additionnal details:**

- I can `telnet my-domain.io 25` from the Postfix container, from the outside, from the server, but not from the Gitlab container
- I can connect to SMTP(s) and IMAP(s) from the outside (tested with Thunderbird, can receive and send mail with gitlab@my-domain.io)
- Absolutely no log on the Postfix container when I run a test on Gitlab
- No specific rule on the firewall

**Configuration used on Thunderbird:**

```
Server Name: my-domain.io
Port: 465
User Name: gitlab@my-domain.io
Authentication method: Normal password
Connection Security: SSL/TLS
```

If I try a `nmap -Pn my-domain.io`:

- from outside world

```
Not shown: 992 filtered ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
143/tcp  open  imap
443/tcp  open  https
465/tcp  open  smtps
587/tcp  open  submission
993/tcp  open  imaps
```

- from outside world in an Ubuntu docker container

```
Not shown: 992 filtered ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
143/tcp  open  imap
443/tcp  open  https
465/tcp  open  smtps
587/tcp  open  submission
993/tcp  open  imaps
```

- from the host:

```
Not shown: 990 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
53/tcp   open  domain
80/tcp   open  http
143/tcp  open  imap
443/tcp  open  https
465/tcp  open  smtps
587/tcp  open  submission
993/tcp  open  imaps
```

- from the Gitlab container:

```
Not shown: 997 filtered ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
80/tcp  open  http
443/tcp open  https
```

- from the host in an Ubuntu docker container

```
Not shown: 997 filtered ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
80/tcp  open  http
443/tcp open  https
```

So, ***I suspect this is the root of this problem*** ; but I don't understand why...

Why docker container from the host itself has these ports filtered when nmap the domain ?

Does someone have any clue ?

Thanks !

Comment: There's a good question here: why is the GitLab container resolving `my-domain.io` to itself? Is it possible you have this entry in `/etc/hosts` on your server? If so, that's probably the cause of the problem.

Comment: @sytech Nop, on the host there is a nginx configuration file that redirect `gitlab.my-domain.io` requests to the Gitlab container. I just don't understand why the nmap result is different between inside/outside the container :/

Comment: Ok, but the nginx configuration won't affect DNS. You mentioned that `my-domain.io` is being resolved to localhost from the gitlab server, which shouldn't happen unless there's a misconfiguration. How is your DNS currently configured?

Comment: @systech Oh, I said "maybe" because I really don't understand what happend ; if I ping my-domain.io from the container, I got the public IP. What can make this ports "filtered" from inner the container ?

Comment: @sytech I removed the part when I talk about possible localhost loop, and I added some tests with generic Ubuntu containers ; it seems that with a container on the host, I cannot see these ports, but with the same container outside, I can :/ What's this devilry...

Comment: Ok it comes from ufw rules. I have to investigate why they're applied on the host but not on the outside world.